# Clickhouse Data source name not found and no default driver

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to connect from c#+.Net throught odbc ([clikhouse-odbc](https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-odbc)).

Below is the code i have

```
var builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Driver =
"E:\...\clickhouse-odbc-master\vs\x64\clickhouseodbc.dll";
builder.Add("SERVER", "....");
builder.Add("DATABASE", "default");
builder.Add("PORT", 8123);
builder.Add("FRAMED", 0);
var connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver = Click House ANSI; Host = ***; Port =***");
//Also tried below
//var connection = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
return connection;
```

When I run, I have the exception:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'.

I have also installed the driver and configured as in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add builder.Driver as below:

```
      var builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Driver =
            "E:\<path>\clickhouseodbc.dll";
        builder.Add("SERVER", "...");
        builder.Add("DATABASE", "default");
        builder.Add("PORT", 8123);
        builder.Add("FRAMED", 0);
        builder.Driver = "ClickHouse ANSI";
        var connection = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
```